# Difference between release lock and clean up

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am Tortoise SVN 1.14, and I've trouble understanding the difference between release lock and clean up action. Are they not supposed to do the same thing, unlocking the locked files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple meaning of locks in subversion.

There is "lock" that is used to describe exclusion between users to avoid clashing commits. This is usually done on binary files.

Then there is another lock called working copy lock.This basically internal to subversion. This prevents collusion between multiple subversion clients working on the same working copy. This is seen in the status output. This is the one that is removed by the `svn cleanup` command.

This lock on working copy can also happen when subversion is interrupted in mid process. So this would mean some unfinished operations remain on working copy. The `svn cleanup` also searches for these and remove these administrative locks from the working copy.